# SQL connection string broker

Tags: sql, architecture, connection-string

My company has a lot of SQL instances with a lot of databases on each instance. Those instances are referenced by a lot of custom code in a lot of different web and application servers. The technology stack on any given server can be at various stages of the lifecycle. It's a maintenance nightmare. I'm in the process of migrating a SQL 2000 instance with thousands of unorganized tables and an unknown set of apps hitting these tables.

I realize my problem is a poorly architected and implemented infrastructure but there's nothing I can do about that right now. What I'm considering is setting up some type of central connection string broker that serve connection strings. Applications will call the broker to get the appropriate connection string.

I guess my first question is - does anything like this exist? I'd much rather drop into an existing solution than roll my own. If not, what's the simplest, most transparent approach for creating something to handle this?

My first thought at a solution is a REST web service running on a load balanced web server that stores the underlying connections in some type of configuration file.

I would appreciate any ideas or potential tools to use.

Comment: What aspect of the connection strings are a problem?  And would this effectively be a key-value-pair lookup?  Finally; What aspect of using DNS aliases fails to address your issue(s)?

Comment: I think it would be a key/value lookup but I would probably want to log the lookups. I'd want to cache the lookup in the application. That is most likely going to end up being very application specific. DNS aliasing, in part, assumes that we can move entire systems at once and that isn't the case.

Comment: DNS aliases mentioned by @Dems are all right indeed. Also there are "SQL Client aliases". I assume application would still use the same DB. So you add alias to `hosts` file, something like "db-server old-server-ip" and then just rewrite that IP address without touching app code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Whats your language? In Java we use org.apache.commons.jbcp.BasicDataSource to hold the connection string, which are loaded by String, from a properties/config file. This is quite maintainable.

Comment: It's a mix of languages. We are mostly a microsoft shop but we do have some PHP and ColdFusion and we support MySQL, Access, and FoxPro.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Distributed Hash Table implementations. They basically provide a decentralized place to put your key and value pairs, connection strings in your case.

To name a few, [memcached](http://memcached.org/), [redis](http://redis.io/)  and [hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) can all do what you need.